# Standard Input C: Incorrect string if $ is present

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to take input from the STDIN. If the input string starts with character '$' then the input is not converted to string as it is.

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
     printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
}
```

Can someone please let me know to why C compiler replaces the characters with '0' if it encounters the '$' symbol ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're calling the program from a unix-like shell, and the shell is interpretting `$foo` as a variable name, and substituting it with nothing (because the variable `foo` doesn't exist).  Try using `'$foo'` (with single quotes) instead.

Comment: Also, you're taking a string as a command line argument, not from stdin - they're very different.

Answer (score 10):

It's not your program.  It's your shell interpreting it as a variable, then passing its value to your program.

To work around this, escape the `$` when you invoke the program from your shell.

```
./yourprogram '$arg'
```

Comment: Or `"\$arg"` which would allow other variables to expand.